# Non-human specific synonym of demography?

Tags: synonyms

I want to use the word demography but that is human specific (demography: the scientific study of human populations, esp with reference to their size, structure, and distribution). Is there an alternative which is not human specific, particularly it's for a biological question about the distribution of trees.

Comment: [Tree demography](https://www.google.com/search?q=demography+trees) is used - Perhaps combined with biomass?

Comment: It's more I'm looking for a word that is "the study of populations and population dynamics, distribution, and structure" whilst being non specific about species.

Comment: There seems to be the word populography, but it is quite strange. http://sciencelinks.jp/j-east/article/199916/000019991699A0657623.php

Comment: It does look strange, is it a real word?

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, _tree demography_ is used, and though it is fairly uncommon, it is fine as it would be clearly understood in the circles regularly using such jargon / subject-specific terminology. This illustrates the phenomenon known as _extension_ (a word widening its meaning), one of the avenues of semantic change. There is no more established alternative, and this new usage should not lead to any confusion. _Animal demography_ and _plant demography_ are similar extensions, according to Google data.

Comment: I think some variant of _population_ will indeed be your best bet but could you give us an example sentence? The specifics might depend on which aspect of the tree's distribution you are studying (good to see you here by the way :) ).

Comment: Demography is “the study of the size, territorial distribution, and composition of population, changes therein, and the components of such changes.” -- Hauser and Duncan. It's not necessarily human-specific: Plant Demography, Animal Demography, Avian Demography, Fish Demography, Single-species Demography, Wildlife Demography ...

Comment: Have you searched around?

Comment: *Population* is derived from *people*, but it applies to all animate, and even inanimate, entities.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds to be a specific example of [population ecology](http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/ecology/journal/10144).

> The term "population" is interpreted differently in various sciences:
>   In human demography a population is a set of humans in a given area.
>   In genetics a population is a group of interbreeding individuals of the same species, which is isolated from other groups.
>   In population ecology a population is a group of individuals of the same species inhabiting the same area

(from http://home.comcast.net/~sharov/PopEcol/lec1/whatis.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an accurate corresponding synonym it will have to be a neologism - DENDRODEMOGRAPHY; and I see nothing wrong with that term.

Otherwise plant demography as suggested is perfectly acceptable.